# Javascript: change color on click and disable rest icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

So I have 6 icons, initially all are grey except one which is treated as selected. If click on some other icon that icon should be enabled and the other one should be turned grey. I'm using `classList.toggle("selected");` to change it but I'm not getting desired result. Here is the code.

CSS

```
.selected {
    color : #012b72;
}
```

HTML

```
<i class="selected icon-toggle"></i>
<i class="icon-toggle"></i>
<i class="icon-toggle"></i>
<i class="icon-toggle"></i>
<i class="icon-toggle"></i>
<i class="icon-toggle"></i>
```

JavaScript

```
icons=document.getElementsByClassName("icon-toggle");

 for(i=0;i<icons.length;i++){       
   icons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
     this.classList.toggle("selected");
   });
 }
```

Comment: your array does not include already selected icon element. In that case will be remain selected element, not?

Comment: I'm sorry I missed that here, it's present in original code.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(i).each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.click(function(){
        $(i).each(function() {
          if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
          }
        });
        $this.addClass("selected");
      });
    });
```

Comment: First you are answering for readers, so please add explanation. Second, OP has not tagged `jQuery`, so answering using it can go against you. Third, you do not need loop. I'll leave figuring how to do it without loop to you

Comment: @Khacho next time please tag jQuery if you are using it

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, try with something like this:

```js
icons = document.getElementsByClassName("icon");

for (i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {

  icons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    for (i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
      icons[i].classList.remove('selected');
    }

    this.classList.toggle("selected");

  });

}
```

```css
.selected {
  color: #012b72;
}
```

```html
<i class="icon selected">A</i>
<i class="icon">B</i>
<i class="icon">C</i>
<i class="icon">D</i>
<i class="icon">E</i>
<i class="icon">F</i>
```

Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/usks0e9c/

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. It will launch a popup where you can paste your code and make an executable snippet

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

#### Idea

- Fetch all elements with `icon-toggle` and `selected` class.
- Remove `selected` class from them excluding `this`.
- Add `selected` class to current element.

  **Pure JS**

```js
var icons=document.getElementsByClassName("icon-toggle")
for (i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
  icons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var actives = document.querySelectorAll(".icon-toggle.selected");
    var selected = "selected";
    for(var i = 0; i < actives.length; i++){
      if(actives[i] !== this)
      actives[i].classList.remove(selected)
    }
    this.classList.toggle(selected);
  });
}
```

```css
.icon-toggle {
  color: gray;
}

.selected {
  color: #012b72;
}
```

```html
<i class="selected icon-toggle">icon 1</i>
<i class="icon-toggle">icon 2</i>
<i class="icon-toggle">icon 3</i>
<i class="icon-toggle">icon 4</i>
<i class="icon-toggle">icon 5</i>
<i class="icon-toggle">icon 6</i>
```

---

**jQuery**

```js
$('.icon-toggle').on('click', function(){
  $(".icon-toggle.selected").not(this).removeClass('selected');
  $(this).toggleClass('selected')
})
```

```css
.icon-toggle {
  color: gray;
}

.selected {
  color: #012b72;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="selected icon-toggle">icon 1</i>
<i class="icon-toggle">icon 2</i>
<i class="icon-toggle">icon 3</i>
<i class="icon-toggle">icon 4</i>
<i class="icon-toggle">icon 5</i>
<i class="icon-toggle">icon 6</i>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I need more help. I have with icons a text which tell what Icon it is, so when I click on the icon even it's corresponding text should change color, can you help?

Comment: Can you create a sample JSFiddle? That will help us debug and check behaviour. As for now, wrap both icon and text in a wrapper div and add class to this div instead of icon

Comment: @Khacho and what should I do with it? Please also tell what ?

Comment: @Khacho Please find updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/fure8rj5/1/) with resolution and comments (*in js and css*)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vanilla JavaScript implementation:

```js
var icons = document.querySelectorAll('.icon-toggle')

function deselect (icon) {
  icon.classList.remove('selected')
}

function selectThis () {
  icons.forEach(deselect)
  this.classList.add('selected')
}

icons.forEach(function (icon) {
  icon.addEventListener('click', selectThis)
})
```

```css
/* contrast! */
.icon-toggle {
  color: #ccc;
}

.selected {
  color: #012b72;
}
```

```html
<i class="selected icon-toggle">Icon</i>
<i class="icon-toggle">Icon</i>
<i class="icon-toggle">Icon</i>
<i class="icon-toggle">Icon</i>
<i class="icon-toggle">Icon</i>
<i class="icon-toggle">Icon</i>
```